# MySQL how to group by and select certain text from multiple rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

A credit card company has several credit cards issued to each consumer.

```
CREATE TABLE card (
  cardnumber int PRIMARY KEY,
  customer int,
  balance decimal(9,2),               
  status varchar(10)              
);

INSERT INTO card VALUES ('100', '1', 100.00, 'active');
INSERT INTO card VALUES ('101', '1', 100.00, 'expired');
INSERT INTO card VALUES ('102', '2', 100.00, 'limited');
INSERT INTO card VALUES ('103', '2', 100.00, 'locked');
```

A report is desired consisting of one row per cardholder, total balance on all cards, and the least restrictive status in the exact order of: 1. Active, 2. Expired, 3. Limited, 4. Locked.

Cardholder #1 has a card in 'active', and a card in 'expired', the report should show 'active'.
Cardholder #2 has a card in 'limited', and a card in 'locked', the report should show 'limited'.

Query

```
select customer, sum(balance), '?'
from card
group by customer
```

How can the query show just the least restrictive status of the cardholders cards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a separate Table for the "status" of the card. So you could create a simple "CASE WHEN" block in the SQL to handle all that.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE card_status (
status_id int PRIMARY KEY,
message varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO card_status VALUES (1, 'active');
INSERT INTO card_status VALUES (2, 'expired');
...
```

Finally, the SQL:

```
SELECT customer, sum(balance), MIN(status)
FROM card
GROUP BY customer
```

Where u can now filter by the status (Sub-Select, CASE WHEN...)

Answer (score 0):

Normalize the table by changing status to integer and insert a foreign key relationship to a status table then you can select min(status) in the select query

Answer (score 0):

In this question, you can luckily get the answer the following query:

```
select customer, sum(balance) balance, MIN(status) leastRestrictedStatus
from card
group by customer
```

This is due to the fact that, alphabetically, the users least restrictive card statuses are alphabetically the minimum values. Note, the other answers provide better long-term sustainable solutions and mine is only a solution based on the structure of the data presented in this example.